# Using distance or colliders to determine what to render

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have some objects I only want to render within a certain distance of the player. The objects don't have any colliders originally, so I am wondering what would be best for performance. Do I:

- Check distance between object and player and render within a cerain distance
- Add a trigger around my player, add colliders to all objects (using project->physics to make sure the layers only look for each other) and use `OnTriggerEnter/Exit` to determine when to render the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cameras near/far clipping planes (Frustum Culling) to adjust the distance for rendering. 
If you are looking for something more advanced use [occlusion culling](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html) or combination of both:

> Occlusion Culling is a feature that disables rendering of objects when they are not currently seen by the camera
>    because they are obscured (occluded) by other objects. This does not happen automatically in 3D computer graphics since most of the time objects farthest away from the camera are drawn first and closer objects are drawn over the top of them (this is called “overdraw”). Occlusion Culling is different from Frustum Culling. Frustum Culling only disables the renderers for objects that are outside the camera’s viewing area but does not disable anything hidden from view by overdraw. Note that when you use Occlusion Culling you will still benefit from Frustum Culling.

You can also use [Camera.layerCullDistances](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-layerCullDistances.html) if you want different camera cull distances for different objects:

> Normally Camera skips rendering of objects that are further away than farClipPlane. You can set up some Layers to use smaller culling distances using layerCullDistances. This is very useful to cull small objects early on, if you put them into appropriate layers.

Comment: I already use culling. I want to "cull" just a few specific objects here, which is why the standard culling isnt really going to work. I appriciate the answer but should probably be a comment since it doesnt answer the question asked.

Comment: What about Camera.layerCullDistances

Comment: Culling is best for performance. I suggest reading this first [Optimizing graphics performance](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OptimizingGraphicsPerformance.html)

Comment: Your edit to ur comment (that changed it completely) looks like something I could use, thanks! Add the https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-layerCullDistances.html to the answer and I can accept :)